# Yii2 db; dsn with ip local

Tags: php, database, yii, yii2

i have my localhost configured with and other port, i'm trying to use this in the `'yii\db\Connection'`

```
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=192.168.1.5;dbname=db_empresa_juridico',
'username' => 'db_user_jurid',
'password' => '[removed]',
'charset' => 'utf8',
```

but Yii2 still loading, don't show nothing how i can connecting to the db? using local ip?

i need to shared my db at lan

Comment: is your dsn really missing a `'` before the username bit, or is that just a typo? and the extra comma on the password line...

Comment: not, i missing the `'` copyng here but i have this: http://prntscr.com/77vskz

Comment: it work with 127.0.0.1 but no with the other IP 192.168.1.5... (using password: YES)

Comment: is mysql listening on that ip?

Comment: oh no! is only 127.0.0.1 and (localhost)

Comment: You are missing this line: 'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',

Comment: no, I'm not forgetting that line just not the show here ... but I needed the port in the DSN

Comment: If you ever host the site you're making on the internet, you might want to change your database password... and username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the `port=3306` in

`'dsn' => 'mysql:host=192.168.1.5;dbname=db_empresa_juridico;port=3306',`